# custom font symbol for star, how to change in css

Tags: html, css

I have weird issue, I'm using custom font in my project, when I add the * in html code
it appears as a special symbol, I will provide picture for it [symbol appearing instead of *](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plQ2t.png)

```
   <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">
            {{ field.label }}{% if field.field.required %}<span class="asteriskField">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
```

the class asteriskField must render it as *, currently I have made it to not appear,

```
.asteriskField {
    display: none;
}
```

```
/* style.css */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'AlJazeera'; /*a name to be used later*/
    font-display: swap;
    src: url('./fonts/Al-Jazeera-Arabic-Regular.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}
```

So what I should do so the star symbol render as usual ?

I have tried contents: "*" , but it doesn't appear as normal star

Comment: You could reset the font-face for the asteriskField by using `font-family: initial` or `font-family: sans-serif`

Comment: @NikitaKaramov : many thanks! , the star icon appear normally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I took the liberty to turn [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77898145/custom-font-symbol-for-star-how-to-change-in-css?noredirect=1#comment137330662_77898145) into an answer.*

The asterisk gets rendered with the font you've set for the page, which is *Al Jazeera*. You can revert this decision by setting the font family to `initial`:

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: "AlJazeera", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.asteriskField {
  font-family: initial;
}
```

```html
<p>
  This text has the Al Jazeera font, but not the asterisk<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
</p>
```

The difference from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77898289) is that `font-family: none` is not a valid value for `font-family`. It may work, but it is not standardized.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `font-family: none;` to use the default font on the `asterisk`

The result should look like this

[image]

```html
<p class="asteriskField">*</p>
<p>*</p>
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "AlJazeera";
  src: url("./Al-Jazeera-Arabic-Regular.ttf");
}

html,
body {
  font-family: "AlJazeera", Arial, sans-serif;
}
.asteriskField{
  font-family: none;
}
```